# Python: Moodle login with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, moodle

I am trying to log in to a Moodle website, but it returns the "you haven't logged in yet" page, which means authentication wasn't successful. What am I doing wrong? Am I forgetting to set a parameter? Please don't recommend *mechanize*. I want to understand how it works without a library. My code:

```
import cookielib, urllib, urllib2, getpass

# not the actual site, but still a Moodle example
theurl = 'https://moodle.pucrs.br/login/index.php'

username= raw_input("\tusername: ")
password= getpass.getpass("\tpassword: ")

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)


# set headers
opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-agent', ('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; '
                   'Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'))
]

try:
    #req = opener.open(theurl, data)
    req = opener.open(theurl)
except IOError, e:
    print "It looks like the username or password is wrong."

# == test ==

# visit "my courses":
req = opener.open("https://moodle.pucrs.br/my/‎")
content = ''.join(req.readlines())
print(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I login to site with urllib:

```
self.cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(


    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookieJar),
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))

self.opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36")]


forms = {"username": #username here ,
         "password": #password here
        }

data = urllib.urlencode(forms)
req = urllib2.Request('http://moodle.pucrs.br/login/index.php',data)
res = self.opener.open(req)
self.login_html = res.read()
```

If you look in the HTML of the login page the names of the two forms are `password` and `username` then you want to send a request then open that request using the opener you made

test this out and tell me if it works!

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I've noticed some things I've added, like HTTPSHandler(), were unecessary. I'll have to look into the difference between CookieJar() and LWPCookieJar().

Comment: yeah I just use this same login for most sites so i keep some unnecessary stuff. Glad I could help! :)